# (Better) Solution for creating new models in chain of before_create methods.

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4, transactions, associations

Before I show you code let me explain it really quick:

- There are 3 models: Payment, Publication and Client.
- Client `has_many :payments`, Publication `has_one :payment` and Payment `belongs_to` both of them
- Publication `has_one :user` through other models ;)
- Client has field `balance` which represents money/funds (like bank account). Balance must **NOT** be below 0.

So how it does *(not)* work now:

- Controller calls `Publication.create` with arguments which contains inter alia `price`.
- Method `before_create :create_payment` inside `Publication` is called. This method contains only this line of code: `Payment.create(client: client, amount: price, publication: self)`
- We are inside `Payment` class now. Inside this class there is `before_create :update_client_balance`. This method calls `client.balance + amount` *(amount represents price)* and then client.save
- Now we go to `Client` model which should validate is `balance` `numericality: { greater_than_or_equal_to: 0,`
- If balance would be below 0 none of all actions should be rollbacked. I mean both `Publication` and `Payment` should **NOT** be created and `Client` balance should be unchanged.

The problem shows up in `before_create :create_payment` inside `Publication` class. So  in order to proper association I need to send `Publication.id` to `Payment` model. But sending `self` doesn't seem to work now. What is more: while running this code (so on `Publication.create()`) callback `create_payment` goes to infinite loop! Payment isn't ever created.

When I started to think about I assumed it shouldn't all happen in `AR callbacks` (should it?). I started to think about creating custom `service` to it (plain old ruby object) but I'm not sure about it. I'm trying to keep highest encapsulation between all classes (they should all care about themselves on their own [so I guess `Publication` should ask for `Client` balance... `Client` should care about it in `validate_numicality_of`.])

The question is: should still stick with `before_create` in situation described above?

- If yes what's the best solution to make it work.
- If no what's the best place and method to make it work?

Comment: You can't use `create` on associations in a `before_create` because the parent isn't yet persisted. If you use build on the associations you should be find and when you call save on the `Publication` it will save the rest of the nested objects.  You could however move this to the controller and build it using the `params`. Or by structuring your form correctly you could create them all at once using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` on your model.

Comment: The problem is that Payment/Client validators have to be executed before saving Publication (so if Payment fails Publication should never be created)

Comment: If you use build and then attempt to save the parent object this will happen (or it should)